# Parquet file size 0 after converting csv to parquet

Tags: scala, csv, hadoop, hdfs, parquet

In my case i used Spak-shell to convert csv file into parquet file, my csv file size was 126mb after converting to parquet file hadoop shows that the file size is 0 although i can read the parquet file using dataframes is it normal or my hadoop cluster is not working right
[hadoop web ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhqhk.png)

[my hdfs dfs -ls command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjYbz.png)

Comment: You're probably looking at the directory containing actual parquet files. Directory size is 0.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but i actually rechecked and i have both csv and parquet file in the same directory, when i list my files i can see the size off the csv file while the parquet file is 0

Comment: No, your Data760.csv is a file (attributes -rw-r--r--) but your other two entries are directories (attributes **d**rwxr-xr-x). Try using `hdfs dfs -ls /test/zipcodes.parquet/` to see the actual files.

Comment: You are right i didn't pay attention, Thank you so much ☺☺